# Customize static wordpress pages correctly

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I m building a word press site with a unique theme that i created, now i got like 10 classes of different styles for the static pages in my site.

The question is, when i want to display the content of the page, with all the forms images and text, how should i do that? With the text editor where the user usually insert his content for the posts in regular `wp` website? Or should i insert the content images and forms hard coded in the `php` custom page template of those static pages?

In the text editor if i insert some `html` in edit as `html` it's becoming a mess it doesn't seems right to create sections and `div` where the user regularly just put his raw content, and anyway adding more content to a static page in the future will require my intervention to wrap it with `css` sections and div's definitions and classes...

By the other hand to write raw data with images and forms in the `php` custom page template doesn't seems to me the right choice... Is it normal to do so for static pages?

Thanks everyone!

Comment: refer this link

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VeYUUtkWiAo
https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/
https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wordpress static pages, by default contains text and images that you can put into it using the Wordpress text editor. This content is known as "The Content" in WP context.

If you want to put into your static page some elements that cannot be setted by the text editor (like your own forms, per example) you'll need to create your own **page template** with *hard-coded* elements.

Example:

```
<?php /* Template Name: My custom page template */ ?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<div id="article">
<div class="date"></div>
    <!-- Your own custom content here -->

</div>
<div class="clear"> 
    <?php if ( comments_open() ) : ?><div id="comments"><?php comments_template('', true); ?> </div>
</div><?php endif; ?>

<?php endwhile; ?> 

<?php endif; ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Hey thabk you! You getting close to what i need, i want to customize with css the elements that return from the_content() i want to wrap them with sections for example or put between two paragraphs of text and images a custom form i created... What is the proper way to do it?

Comment: By default, all templates and pages of Wordpress has the `get_header()` function (don't remove it!), that means you have the template's stylesheet here. Use the `style.css` file of your template to do it. Put all the CSS in this file is the proper way ;-)

Comment: But how i make some of the content in the user editor to be under <section> with class A and the other content in the same page with class B for example? Its seems to me that the_content() is one chunk i can customize part of the content with tags and sections and the other parts with different tags and sections and class. I can do it only by edit in the user editor with edit html and not text visualizer... Or i can delete everything in the text visualizer and put all in the php template including the content

Comment: `the_content` is a piece of HTML, you can wrap it into your own class or create classes inside.

My recomendation, if you want to put custom content and you won't need the text editor, you can put all in the template.

Answer (score 0):

I normally will put those styles into styles.css of your theme. Even if it's images that will be standard images for the theme or shortcodes available to the user you want it to load from within the styles.css page. You don't want to do anything static like that with WordPress. Updates can mess it up as well as having issues with inline css messing up your SEO for the site.

If the user needs to do something in the editor to have an image show or something like that you can do it as a shortcode. That's normally going to be your best approach. Have you used shortcodes and loaded the images that before?

Comment: So if i understand you, you suggest to use shortcode like [company-open] and it will generate something like <section class="open-company"> and after the user will insert his content and images i use shortcode that will generate the closing section tag, and for forms like example i will use a whole custom shortcode that i will write. Am i got you?